# Changing png image on click but new image is reverting to original image after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for the winded title but kind of hard to explain in one line.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- On click of list "item 2", I'm changing the image of my blue-plus icon into a yellow-plus icon and vice versa.  (DONE)
- Clicking the plus icon will animate header/jumbotron section up while changing the plus icon into a minus icon (DONE)
- However when I click on list "item 2", which changes blue icon into yellow, then clicking that icon to animate header/jumbotron up, the yellow icon turns back into the blue icon. I want the yellow icon to stay yellow anytime "item 2" is clicked and blue icon to stay blue anytime "item 1" is clicked.

```js
//ANIMATE UP/DOWN ON CLICK OF ICON
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".topBarInner").click( function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
   
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
   $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
   $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
   $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)");
        }else {
   $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
   $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
   $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png)");
  } 

  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
  return false;

 });
    
});
    
//CHANGE ICON & BACKGROUND COLOR
        
function changeColor1() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#6aabcb');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#bdd2f1');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)');
}

function changeColor2() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#e4b028');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#ffce4e');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png)');
}
```

```css
.headerRow{
 padding:52px 0;
    position: relative;
 } 
    
.jumbotron {
 margin-top:-10px;
 padding:175px 0 0px 0;
 background-color:#6aabcb;
 color: white;
 position:relative;
 }
    
.topBar{
 height:11px;
 width:98%;
 background-color:#bdd2f1;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:85px;
 }
 
.topBarInner{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
 height:28px;
 width:28px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
    
.clicked{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png);
 }
```

```html
<link href="http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row headerRow">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/logo.jpg"/></a> 
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="jumbotron"></div>

<div id="contentContainer">   
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="topBar"><div class="topBarInner"></div></div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeColor1()">Item 1</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor2()">Item 2</a></li>    
            </ul>     
       </div>
    </div> 
</div><!--/container-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix with `!important` keyword in css and updating the dom with classes instead of changing the styles of selected classes. The `!important` keyword is not a good practice, but that's the only thing I found to fix it so far. I'll take a look at it tomorrow and see if I can help further. Also, I've moved the link for jQuery from bottom of `<body` to the `<head` section, since all libraries should be there. I've put the local javascript script in the bottom of `body` instead as recommended. Here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css">
    <link href="http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="icon" href="./bilder/icon.ico">  
    <title>Kletterwelt - Home</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row headerRow">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/logo.jpg"/></a> 
      </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron"></div>

  <div id="contentContainer">   
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="topBar"><div class="topBarInner"></div></div>  
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
              <ul> 
                  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changeColor1()">Item 1</a></li>   
                  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor2()">Item 2</a></li>    
              </ul>     
          </div>
      </div> 
  </div><!--/container-->
  <script src="scripts2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Additional classes in CSS:

```
.jumbotron-colored {
  background-color: #e4b028 !important;
}
.topBar-colored {
  background-color: #ffce4e !important;
}
.topBarInner-colored {
  background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png) !important;
}
```

`changeColor()` functions in JS file changes:

```
function changeColor1() {
    $('.jumbotron').removeClass('jumbotron-colored');
    $('.topBar').removeClass('topBar-colored');
    $('.topBarInner').removeClass('topBarInner-colored');
}

function changeColor2() {
    $('.jumbotron').addClass('jumbotron-colored');
    $('.topBar').addClass('topBar-colored');
    $('.topBarInner').addClass('topBarInner-colored');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! almost there! 

Just missing the minus sign when , "item 2"  then "yellow plus icon" is clicked.